# How to display Meta Field Value?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I am trying to display the value of a Meta field on single.php.
The Meta Key is 'current_rank'.

I tried...

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'current_rank', true);  ?>
```

This code does not output anything, not even an error.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running that in The Loop? Are you certain a value is stored in 'current_rank' for that specific post?

Answer (score 4):

You're very likely running that outside of the loop.

To confirm, try the following:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();

$current_rank = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'current_rank', true);

echo 'Post ID is: ' . $post_id;
echo '<br> Current Rank is: ' . $current_rank;
```

Are you getting post ID printed on the page? Is the current rank showing empty? Then the `current_rank` meta value for this post is definitely empty.

Comment: Figured it out. I the meta key was _current_rank not current_rank.

Comment: Outstanding... ;)